# Subscribe Observable, Can not get the value

Tags: angular

## *Subscribe  Observable, Can not get the value.*

### Current behavior

- I run a nodejs server name it N . It's provide data . Then , I run a angular application name it A .
- A and N establish socket connection . A act client. N act server.
- N there is a regular task to send data to the client A
- In A , I used a service to received the data . Can get it .
- The service injection a component , But can not get the subscription data in the component .

### Expected behavior

- Can get the subscription data in the component .

### Minimal reproduction of the problem with instructions

- angular service:

  ```
  createObservableSocket(url: string, id: number): Observable<any> {   
    let a = new Observable<string>(
    observer => {
      this.ws.onmessage = (event) => {
        observer.next(event.data);
        console.log('event data:', event.data); // event data: [{"productId":1,"bid":3616.8217831199527}]
      }
      this.ws.onerror = (event) => observer.error(event);
      this.ws.onopen = (event) => this.sendMessage({productId: id});
      this.ws.onclose = (event) => observer.complete();
    }
  );
  console.log('a:', a); // [Observable object]
  let b = a.map(message => {
    JSON.parse(message);
  });
  console.log('b:', b); // [Observable object]
  return b;
  ```

  }

  ```
  sendMessage(message: any) {
    console.log('client ws service msg:', JSON.stringify(message)); //client ws service msg: {"productId":1}
    this.ws.send(JSON.stringify(message)); 
  }
  ```
- angular component

  ```
  watchProduct() {
    this.isWatched = !this.isWatched;

    this.wsService.createObservableSocket('ws://localhost:8085', 
    this.product.id)
      .subscribe(
        products => {
          console.log('component received:', products); //component  received: undefined
          let product = products.find( p => p.productId === this.product.id);
          this.currentBid = product.bid;
        }
      );
    }
  ```

### Environment

```
Angular version: 4.2.4

Browser:
- [ ] Chrome (desktop) version 60.0.3112.101

For Tooling issues:
- Node version: v8.1.0
- Platform: Windows 10
```

### Other:

- Why can not subscribe data, please help me. Thanks!

Comment: I believe it has something to do with reassigning initial Observable. Can you please try to return `a` without `.map()` and just see if you'll get the data in the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `return` data:

So change this :

```
a.map(message => {
  JSON.parse(message);
});
```

To :

```
a.map(message => {
  return JSON.parse(message);
});

// OR

a.map(message => JSON.parse(message));
```

Comment: @ziyangding, please replace the code block with given one and try , you are not returning anything from `a.map`.

Comment: createObservableSocket(url: string, id: number): Observable<any> {
   this.ws = new WebSocket(url);
   return new Observable<string>(
     observer => {
    this.ws.onmessage = (event) => {
      observer.next(event.data);
      console.log('event data:', event.data);
    }
    this.ws.onerror = (event) => observer.error(event);
    this.ws.onclose = (event) => observer.complete();
    this.ws.onopen = (event) => this.sendMessage({productId: id});
     }
   ).map(message => {JSON.parse(message)});
    }

Comment: @ziyangding then just change `JSON.parse(message)` to `return JSON.parse(message)` or just remove curly brackets before and after `JSON.parse(message)`

Comment: I delete the curly brackets，it's worked! thank very match!

Comment: @ziyangding, will you please accpet the answer and also upvote it ?

Comment: @ziyangding, left to my answer there is up down arrow , click on up and bewow that arrow there will be right sign , click on that also.

Comment: Then please click on right symbol. below the arrows.

Comment: @ziyangding, Yey got it , :)